# Using delete on a LINQ to Sql Data Context with an Interface - 'Interface is not mapped as a table'

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, generics

I have three entities in my data context which inherit `IFileData`, but I want just a single delete method. How can this be achieved?

The code below give the error `The type "IFileData" is not mapped as a Table`.

```
    public void ImageDelete<T>(T instance) where T : class, IFileData
    {
        using (var db = this.CreateDataContext())
        {
            db.GetTable<T>().DeleteOnSubmit(instance);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

The only solution I have so far is to do a switch on the `.GetType()` which is a bit messy.

Thanks!

**Solution:**

As Marc mentioned, I used `dynamic` in the calling method:

`ImageDelete((dynamic)(instance as IFileData));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could build the `Expression` manually, using the actual `T` ? Untested (since that `Delete` doesn't exist?), but something like:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(
       Expression.Property(param, "Key"),
       Expression.Constant(instance.Key)
    ), param);
```

This then isn't bound to `IFileData`, but to `T`. It will fail, however, if `IFileData.Key` is implemented via explicit interface implementation - there must be an obvious `Key` field/property on `T`.

Then:

```
var table = db.GetTable<T>();
var obj = table.SingleOrDefault(lambda);
if(obj != null) table.DeleteOnSubmit(obj);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code does not compile on the second Expression (`Expression<Func<T, bool>>`), it says `'Class name is not valid at this point.'`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code does not compile on the second Expression (`Expression<Func<T, bool>>`), it says `'Class name is not valid at this point.'`. The delete extension method is from CodeSmith, which basically turns your lambda into SQL and does a batch delete. I'll change it to use `DeleteOnSubmit(instance)`. (apparently I spent more than 5 minutes editing my comment :()

Comment: Ok great but what do I do with my lambda? I'm not that familiar with expression trees.... (also I changed the question a little, any chance you could update the answer? :))

Comment: Thanks for your help Marc, I think there is a slight misunderstanding here, the problem is that `T` is of type `IFileData`, so it is actually the line `db.GetTable<T>()` which throws the exception of `The type "IFileData" is not mapped as a Table`.

Comment: @Stephen then use the *correct* `T` ;p If it isn't known, there are 2 options: 1: use `instance.GetType()` and `MakeGenericMethod` and reflection to get hold of the right methods - a lot ugly; or 2: in 4.0, in the calling code, use `dynamic`; i.e. instead of `ImageDelete(obj)` use `ImageDelete((dynamic)obj)`. This will then use the *actual* `T` at runtime.

Comment: Perfect! I used the dynamic cast in the call to the method and it solved all my problems! Thanks for your persistence.